# C# limiting the pooling connection

Tags: c#, database, threadpool, pooling

I know that in c# default pooling size  is 100 but i wanted to limit the pooling size to 20  and remaining request to db has to be queued ,after fixed time unprocessed request has to be dismissed 
 i tried the following connection string and sent 100 request at once by using postman but it processed all the request and did't through any exceptions.

```
connection.ConnectionString = "Server=servername;Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=true;Connection Timeout=0;Connection Lifetime=30;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=20;Pooling=true;"
```

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . **Why** do you want to do this?

Comment: i tried with 20,did't work so i tried with 110(more than default) but nothing changed

Comment: @mjwills i am trying to connect to the data base and want to create only 20 connections to it so that it can create only 20 sessions (or handle 20 requests).I thought pooling is the solution

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean you used more than 20 connections from the pool. How did you send 100 requests all at once from Postman? I know of no way to send concurrent requests in Postman without possibly a pre/post request script doing ajax.

Comment: Why do you want only 20? What is the issue you are experiencing from having more than 20?

Comment: changing the max pool size doesn't cause queuing - it causes attempts to get the underlying connection to throw exceptions... if you want *queuing*, you probably want something more like a semaphore, but you'll need to be careful not to deadlock yourself *and* to always always use try/finally around semaphore acquisitions, so you don't leak them and run out...

Comment: @MarcGravell from here i thought it will create queue https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling

Comment: @Crowcoder i know it won't be concurrent but i used postman collections

Comment: @ashwathhegde did you mean to provide a link? but: no, it throws an `InvalidOperationException` with the text "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached." ...

Comment: @mjwills yes but i was not getting any exception

Comment: @ashwathhegde well... what kind of connection *is it*? what actually is `connection`? note: not all ado.net providers implement pooling

Comment: @MarcGravell  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())

Comment: @ashwathhegde Postman collections run sequentially so you are almost certainly releasing the connection back to the pool before the next request hits.

Comment: @Crowcoder yes. i logged the timing .it takes .05-1 sec each

Comment: @Crowcoder can you please tell me any other way to send  concurrent requests

Comment: @mjwills its clients requirement for their api

Comment: @ashwathhegde there are tools, like RestCommander (?) that can do it or write some C# that fires async HttpRequests that does not await until they are all in flight.

Comment: @Crowcoder thaks alot . i think this willl help me  a lot

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a form of resource locking with 20 locks work? e.g.

```
static readonly object SomeLock = new object();
using (var lck = new CodeLock()) 
{
   var ok = lck.Lock(SomeLock, timeout) 
   // do stuff, connect to db
}

public struct CodeLock : IDisposable
{
    private object lockedObject;
    private bool lockTaken;

    public bool Lock(object someLock, int timeout)
    {
        lockedObject = someLock;
        Monitor.TryEnter(someLock, timeout, ref lockTaken);
        if (lockTaken == false)
        {
            // didn't acquire lock within timeout
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (lockedObject == null) return;
        if (lockTaken)
        {
            lockTaken = false;
            Monitor.Exit(lockedObject);
        }
    }
}
```